# Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown

Tags: java, exception, constructor, testng

Apologies if this has been answered before, but I have had a look and cant find anything that helps me. I am getting the error in the title when trying to run the following code. Does anybody know what explicit constructor could be used to fix this error ?

```
public class HomePageTest extends TestBase{

    LoginPage loginPage;
    HomePage homePage;
    ShopByDepartmentPage shopByDepartmentPage;
    JamiesAmazonPage jamiesAmazonPage;
    TodaysDealsPage todaysDealsPage;
    MyAccountPage myAccountPage;
    BasketPage basketPage;

    public HomePageTest() throws IOException {
        super();
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        initialization();
        loginPage = new LoginPage();
        shopByDepartmentPage = new ShopByDepartmentPage();
        jamiesAmazonPage = new JamiesAmazonPage();
        todaysDealsPage = new TodaysDealsPage();
        myAccountPage = new MyAccountPage();
        basketPage = new BasketPage();
        homePage = loginPage.login(prop.getProperty("username"), 
        prop.getProperty("password"));
    }
}
```

My Test Base Code is:

```
public static WebDriver driver;
public static Properties prop;

public TestBase() throws IOException {

    try {
        prop = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:\\Users\\mcalpinej\\Desktop\\POM Project\\POM_Project\\src\\main\\java\\Config\\config.properties");
        prop.load(fis);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void initialization() {

    if (prop.getProperty("browser").equals("firefox"))
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Users\\mcalpinej\\Desktop\\POM Project\\POM_Project\\src\\main\\java\\Resources\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    else if (prop.getProperty("browser").equals("chrome"))
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Users\\mcalpinej\\Desktop\\POM Project\\POM_Project\\src\\main\\java\\Resources\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(TestUtil.PAGE_LOAD_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TestUtil.IMPLICIT_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
}
```

Full stack trace code is as follows:

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setUp
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by 
implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

at Pages.ShopByDepartmentPage.<init>(ShopByDepartmentPage.java:5)
at TestCases.HomePageTest.setUp(HomePageTest.java:38)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:523)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

When I try to put the @Before method into a try catch as below I am still getting the same error message :

```
 @BeforeMethod
public void setUp() {
    initialization();
    try {
        loginPage = new LoginPage();
        shopByDepartmentPage = new ShopByDepartmentPage();
        jamiesAmazonPage = new JamiesAmazonPage();
        todaysDealsPage = new TodaysDealsPage();
        myAccountPage = new MyAccountPage();
        basketPage = new BasketPage();
        homePage = loginPage.login(prop.getProperty("username"), prop.getProperty("password"));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

ShopByDepartmentPage code:

```
public class ShopByDepartmentPage extends TestBase{

@FindBy(xpath="//tr//td[1]//div[1]//ul[1]//li[1]")
WebElement videos;

@FindBy(xpath="//li[@class='nav_first']//a[@class='nav_a'][contains(text(),'Books')]")
WebElement books;

@FindBy(xpath="//li[@class='nav_first']//a[@class='nav_a'][contains(text(),'Amazon Music Unlimited')]")
WebElement music;

@FindBy(xpath="//tr//td[2]//div[4]//ul[1]//li[6]//a[1]")
WebElement computerGames;
```

Comment: please include the full stack trace

Comment: Why does your constructor have an throws IO clause? Constructors should never do any logic like reading or writing from/to files

Comment: can you paste TestBase code?

Comment: @jamiemca you should include that info (trace and other classes) in your post, not in comments. It is difficult to read

Comment: @elbraulio thanks I have done that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the immediate error reported is an `Unresolved compilation problem` hints at something else: This type of error can be produced by bytecode compiled with the eclipse compiler, which does incremental compilation.

It seems like at some point you didn't have the explicit default constructor in your derived class, and your IDE (probably eclipse, but might be another one using the eclipse compiler) and/or build system hasn't been able to recompile that class since, so you're still running the old bytecode.

Try doing a clean build and watch out for other compilation errors. If you have a proper build system like maven or gradle, close your IDE and run a clean & build using that. It is possible for the build system to pick up `.class` files generated on the fly by the IDE.

Comment: Hi @ohlec. You are correct that I am using eclipse as my IDE. I have trieddoing a clean build however and I am still getting the same error message.

Comment: @jamiemca Did you try deleting all `.class` files and compiling with `javac` (e.g. gradle or maven, or just by hand) with eclipse closed? It would really surprise me if this wasn't an eclipse compiler issue.

Comment: @jamiemca Also, please check that the version of the `.java` file on disk that you are compiling does indeed have the explicit nullary constructor with the `throws IOException` declaration

Comment: Just to check as I am quite new to this, do you mean navigating to the folder where HomePageTest is stored in cmd line and executing the following command : javac HomePageTest.java ? If not could you please point me in the right direction

Comment: @jamiemca I was hoping you are using a build system like maven or gradle to do this for you . Those use `javac` as their compiler, not the eclipse compiler. I can't really answer your question not knowing how your project is laid out (what your compile-time classpath is, where the binaries go, etc). If you exclusively use eclipse to build, please just delete all `.class` files, clean the project, and rebuild it watching out for compile error messages.

Comment: I use Maven in my project, but i am unsure what you mean by compiling with javac. Do you mean that is hould scrub the maven repository and let it re-build my workspace ?

Comment: @jamiemca In that case, just closing Eclipse, going to your project directory and then doing `mvn clean test` should suffice. Like I said, maven itself will use `javac`.

Comment: @jamiemca Also, yes, scrubbing the local repository might also be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your help @ohlec. This has solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your unit testing framework can't handle a checked `Exception` being thrown from a Constructor.

The obvious advise is - don't throw the `Exception`. If the framework isn't allowing it, it's probably for a good reason - i.e. it might not display the `Exception` in a good way.

If you really do want to do this logic in the constructor, an alternative is to re-throw the `IOException` as a `ExceptionInInitializerError`, which is an unchecked `Exception`.

Comment: My constructor gives an error when I remove the IOException and I get the same error when I try to throw the ExceptionInInitializerError. The only suggestion my IDE makes is to add the throw declaration.

Comment: @jamiemca use a `try catch` to avoid the exception just to check if this is the error or not

Comment: @elbraulio I have tried this and I am still getting the same error message. I have posted the code above

Comment: @jamiemca seems like the error is on `ShopByDepartmentPage`, can you share it?

Comment: @elbraulio all I have in this page at the moment is some xpath locators and their corresponding elements. I have attached the code above

Comment: @jamiemca even though you are catching the IOException, your constructor still declares that it throws it so the framework doesn’t know you’ve fixed anything.

Comment: @Jakg My IDE will not allow me to remove the throws declaration without giving me an error message, and it also will not allow me to put it in a try catch as it says the constructor call must be the first statement in the constructor